# Getting Parse Objects via pointers

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to get a `Reservation` object which contains a pointer to `Restaurant`.

In Parse Cloud code, i am able to get the restaurants objects associated with `Reservations` via `query.include('Restaurant')` in log just before response.success. However, the `Restaurants` reverted back to pointer when i receive the response on client app.

I tried reverted JSSDK version to `1.4.2` & `1.6.7` as suggested in some answers, but it doesn't work for me.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getreservationsforuser', function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user

    console.log(user)

    var query = new Parse.Query('Reservations')

    query.equalTo('User', user)

    query.include('Restaurant')

    query.find({
        success : function(results) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
            response.success(results)
        },
        error : function (error) {
            response.error(error)
        }
    })
})
```

response :

```
..."restaurant":{"__type":"Pointer",
              "className":"Restaurants",
               "objectId":"kIIYe7Z0tD"},...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my code implementation was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly send the pointer objects back from cloud code even though you have included it. You need to manually copy the content of that pointer object to a javascript object. Like below:

```
var restaurant = {}
restaurant["id"] = YOUR_POINTER_OBJECT.id;
restaurant["createdAt"] = YOUR_POINTER_OBJECT.createdAt;
restaurant["custom_field"] = YOUR_POINTER_OBJECT.get("custom_field");
```

ps: in your code you seem do nothing else other than directly send the response back. I think parse REST api might be a better choice in that case.

Comment: could you give more detail on this? how can i include them in the parse object when it's a predefined type `Parse.Object`? i could not make sense with your answer as it would not create a Parse object with it.

How would REST Api be a better choice? any reference/example?